# Prolog printing storage address instead of actual variables

Tags: prolog

I am writing a auto draw program for the Champion League knockout round using Prolog. The code are as follows.

```
/* ChampionLeagueAutoDraw_KnockOutRound */
%% by Zach X.



% some "nice" prolog settings
%
:- set_prolog_flag( prompt_alternatives_on, groundness ).
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [quoted(true),
     portray(true), attributes(portray), max_depth(999), priority(699)]).



%% Dynamic database for team candidates.
:- dynamic team/5.


%% team(name, nationality, rank, group, bool_taken).
team(BayernMunich, Germany, 1, E, 0).
team(AtleticoMadird, Spain, 1, A, 0).
team(RealMadrid, Spain, 1, B, 0).
team(Monaco, France, 1, C, 0).
team(Dortmund, Germany, 1, D, 0).
team(Barcelona, Spain, 1, F, 0).
team(Chelsea, England, 1, G, 0).
team(Porto, Portugal, 1, H, 0).
team(Juventus, Italy, 2, A, 0).
team(Basel, Switzerland, 2, B, 0).
team(Leverkusen, Germany, 2, C, 0).
team(Arsenal, England, 2, D, 0).
team(ManCity, England, 2, E, 0).
team(PSG, France, 2, F, 0).
team(Schalke04, Germany, 2, G, 0).
team(Shaktar, Ukraine, 2, H, 0).



%% Pick the first team ready for matching.
%% When a team is picked, the bool_taken flag is set to 1.
pick(X) :-
    team(X,N,R,G,0),
    retract(team(X,_,_,_,_)),
    assert(team(X,N,R,G,1)),
    match(X,_).

%% Rules for match():
%%  Teams from the same country do not meet;
%%  Teams from the same group do not meet;
%%  Teams with the same rank do not meet;

match(X,Y) :-
    team(X,Nx,Rx,Gx,1),
    team(Y,Ny,Ry,Gy,0),
    X\==Y,
    Nx\==Ny,
    Rx\==Ry,
    Gx\==Gy,
    retract(team(Y,_,_,_,_)),
    assert(team(Y,Ny,Ry,Gy,1)),
    nl,write(X), write(' V.S '), write(Y).

%%  Pick all 8 matches (pretty sure this is not the right way to
%   write it...)
autodraw :-
    pick(_),pick(_),pick(_),pick(_),pick(_),pick(_),pick(_),pick(_).
```

Two questions:

1. When I compiled it there were a ton of singleton warnings with the 16 teams database, why?
2. When autodraw is called, it is supposed to print out the name of the teams in each match, but instead it printed out something like:

   _G2032 V.S _G2033

Why?

Also, I am aware that calling 8 pick predicates in auto draw is not the right way to do it, what I want to make sure all 8 matches all made and printed at once. Is there a better alternative?

===========Update============

```
/* ChampionLeagueAutoDraw_KnockOutRound */
%% by Zach X.



% some "nice" prolog settings
%
:- set_prolog_flag( prompt_alternatives_on, groundness ).
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [quoted(true),
     portray(true), attributes(portray), max_depth(999), priority(699)]).



% Dynamic database for team candidates.
:- dynamic team/5.


% team(name, nationality, rank, group, bool_taken).

team(bayernMunich, germany, 1, e, 0).
team(atleticoMadird, spain, 1, a, 0).
team(realMadrid, spain, 1, b, 0).
team(monaco, france, 1, c, 0).
team(dortmund, germany, 1, d, 0).
team(barcelona, spain, 1, f, 0).
team(chelsea, england, 1, g, 0).
team(porto, portugal, 1, h, 0).
team(leverkusen, germany, 2, c, 0).
team(basel, switzerland, 2, b, 0).
team(juventus, italy, 2, a, 0).
team(arsenal, england, 2, d, 0).
team(manCity, england, 2, e, 0).
team(psg, france, 2, f, 0).
team(schalke04, germany, 2, g, 0).
team(shaktar, ukraine, 2, h, 0).


%% Rules for match():
%%  Teams from the same country do not meet;
%%  Teams from the same group do not meet;
%%  Teams with the same rank do not meet;

match(X,Y) :-
    X\==Y,
    team(X,Nx,Rx,Gx,Bx),
    team(Y,Ny,Ry,Gy,By),
    Bx==0,
    By==0,
    Nx\==Ny,
    Rx\==Ry,
    Gx\==Gy,
    retract(team(X,Nx,Rx,Gx,Bx)),
    assert(team(X,Nx,Rx,Gx,1)),
    retract(team(Y,Ny,Ry,Gy,By)),
    assert(team(Y,Ny,Ry,Gy,1)),
    nl,write(X), write(' V.S '), write(Y).

%%  Pick all 8 matches (Correct way to do it?)
autodraw :-
    match(_,_), fail.
```

After getting rid of pick() and instead calling match directly (calling pick is redundant), auto draw now works almost as I expected, except that it only generates one possible result. I wanted to get all possible 8-pair result. Right now it only prints a fixed list because of the order of the teams entered at the beginning. For example, 'bayernMunich' is always paired with 'basel' because 'bayernMunich' is the first team entered with Rank == 1, and basel is the first team entered that can be legally matched with Bayern (Leverkusen is from Germany).

How can I modify this so that the program can give me all the possible combinations? Looks like I need a way to make prolog randomly access the team database instead of searching it by order. How can I do that?

Comment: A *singleton* variable is a variable that only appears once in a predicate clause. It's sort of like a variable that is *declared but never used* or *assigned a value that's never used* in other languages. Chances are, if you're not sure what it is, it's probably an error as you may have not intended this behavior. It looks like you don't realize that, in Prolog, a variable starts with a capital letter. An atom starts lower case. For your second question, realize that a variable `_` (or a variable that starts with `_`) is an anonymous variable, and it means you don't care what it's value is.

Comment: @lurker Note that a variable that starts with an underscore is not necessarily an anonymous variable. For example, in the clause `a(_X, _Y, _X).`, `_X` is *not* an anonymous variable. Also, `_Y` may or may not be reported as a singleton variable depending on the Prolog system. E.g. look at the (differences between the) warnings printed when compiled the clauses `a(_X, _Y, _X).` and `a(_x, _y, _x).` with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: @PauloMoura yes, indeed, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @lurker I changed all the atoms to lower case and the singleton problems were cleared. Could you tell me how do I realize making 8 matches at once when I call "autodraw"? Right the result contains repetitive matches.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Currently, `autodraw` and descendent predicates iterate through the matches and *write* them to the console. Are you looking instead to collect all of them in a list? By the way, there appear to be only 7 matches (at least when I ran your code in SWI).

Comment: @lurker I saw that, too. The output I want is like:  combination 1:(8 matches); combination 2: (another 8 matches); ...combination X, until all possible combinations are exhausted. Right now it only works out 1 combination and it only matches teams pair by pair without looking at the whole picture (that's why there are only 7 pairs, because the program matches teams in order and last two teams left cannot be paired by the rule. Ideally, when making a 8-match combination, it should make sure that there will be 8 legal pairs.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to separate the logic from IO, and to avoid side effects (like assert/retract) when are not required. They can make your program very hard to debug.

```
match(X,Y) :-
    team(X,Nx,Rx,Gx,_Bx),
    team(Y,Ny,Ry,Gy,_By),
    Nx\==Ny,
    Rx\==Ry,
    Gx\==Gy.

autodraw :-
    forall(match(X,Y), (nl, write(X), write(' V.S '), write(Y))).
```

The last argument of team/5 seems devoted to track the 'join', I think it's useless.

To print formatted output, format it's often a better fit than multiple write:

```
autodraw :-
    forall(match(X,Y), format('~n~w V.S ~w', [X,Y])).
```